# SQL Server commands in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need a command in a `.sql` file for SQL Server 2012 that lets me run strings as commands, like:

```
set @command= 'create table mytable (...);';
run(@command);
```

Preferably with some kind of string format for strings and/or numbers. Usually I do this in C# but I was wondering if I can keep it all in a `.sql` file.

Comment: A `.sql` file is nothing but a plain text file, so of course you can. Load the text file, read the statements, and execute them as you would any other SQL statement or script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, save your SQL command in a `*.sql` file say `test.sql` and use [`SQLCMD Utility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx) to run the sql file in a command prompt like below

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -i test.sql -o result.txt
```

Not sure but if you mean running the `*.sql` file in your [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) code behind; then I would suggest, create a stored procedure and pull up your SQL queries in that stored procedure. Then you can simply call that procedure in your application code instead of reading the SQL file and running them one by one.